Why am I having output problem in VSCode?
I recently installed VS Code and when I write codes in C program like hello world or addition of numbers it always gives output. But when I write escape sequences like \a or \b, VSCode shows red boxes and not the output. Like \a gives a beep sound but my output box shows a "bel" written in red box and I can't find any video on YouTube to fix it.I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but I still can't get the results. Please help me solve this problem of escape sequence.

This is expected, the '\a' character is named BEL in the ascii standard, and '\b' is a backspace, so might not show up. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape

For some history, old mechanical terminals had an actual bell that would make a "pling" sound when the BEL character arrived.

In windows 10 I can't get the bell sound or a character for \a using putch() or printf() anymore.  I think it's still possible because, while running xcopy for backups, occasionally the PC speaker will BEEP because xcopy prints every character of the copied file and path to the console, and some character -- or combination of characters -- will still cause a BEEP.  If I can find out which character(s) I intend to come back here and let you know.

Presumably VS Code wants you to see the output. It's the development environment, not the final user's environment. Note that when run in a Windows console, printf("\a"); emits a beep.

@WeatherVane -- what OS are you using?  printf("\a") and putch('\a')  both fail for me under Win10, regardless of how I set the console -- to legacy mode and what have you.  Please tell OS, compiler, and any peculiar trick(if any) used on the console settings, and thanks much!

@gregspears Windows 7, 64-bit compilation with MSVC 2022 v17.1.1. The console runs %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" Also when compiled with the earlier 32-bit MSVC compiler, with a similar call to set up the environment vars.

Any trick? Elbowed the horrible Windows 10, which did not even allow me to choose when to make system updates.
